# Правильная проверка валидации даты java?

Tags: java, android, дата, проверка

Есть **edittext** в него вводиться дата из datepicker в формате ***dd.MM.yyyy***

```
//считываю выбранный день месяц год
int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
int mon = datePicker.getMonth();
int year = datePicker.getYear();
//в переменную записываю дату строкой
String outdate = String.format("%02d", day) + "." + String.format("%02d", mon + 1) + "." + year;
DateEnterText.setText(outdate); //передаю значение в поле
```

Хочу сделать еще и ручной ввод в **edittext**, но как будет правильнее сделать проверку на валидность (корректность) введенной даты , во-первых что она соответствует формату ***dd.MM.yyyy*** и то что к примеру введенная дата не будет каким нибудь 29 февраля не в високосный год или к примеру  35.03.2020 года. Как правильно это сделать?

При вводе значения вручную в **edittext** у меня уже автоматически проставляются разделительные "точки" через класс **TextWatcher**, и стоит ограничение на количество введенных символов `android:maxLength="10"`, `android:inputType="date"`, так же другими словами порядок ввода вроде как сделан.

Спасибо. я только учусь...сильно не пинайте и это мой первый вопрос тут...

Comment: используйте стандартный widget DatePicker, форматов даты очень много, никто не будет подстраиваться под вас

Comment: то есть просто не заморачиваться на ручной ввод? диалог с DatePicker я уже сделал.

Comment: одна из парадигм мобильного программирования - лучше выбрать чем ввести

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Для ввода даты есть специальный control учитывающий локальные настройки. Но если очень хочется то можно усложнить себе жизнь.

Answer (score 2):

```
      private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

private static final String DATE_PATTERN = 
       "(0?[1-9]|1[012]) [/.-] (0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) [/.-] ((19|20)\\d\\d)";


  /**
  * Validate date format with regular expression
  * @param date date address for validation
  * @return true valid date format, false invalid date format
  */
  public boolean validate(final String date){

  matcher = pattern.matcher(date); 

  if(matcher.matches()){
  matcher.reset();

  if(matcher.find()){
      String day = matcher.group(1);
      String month = matcher.group(2);
      int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));

      if (day.equals("31") && 
        (month.equals("4") || month .equals("6") || month.equals("9") ||
               month.equals("11") || month.equals("04") || month .equals("06") ||
               month.equals("09"))) {
         return false; // only 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 has 31 days
      } 

      else if (month.equals("2") || month.equals("02")) {
           //leap year
           if(year % 4==0){
               if(day.equals("30") || day.equals("31")){
                   return false;
               }
               else{
                   return true;
               }
          }
          else{
              
      if(day.equals("29")||day.equals("30")||day.equals("31")){
                  return false;
              }
              else{
                  return true;
              }
          }
      }

      else{               
          return true;                
      }
  }

  else{
       return false;
  }        
  }
  else{
  return false;
  }              
  }
```

Этот код на метод onClick()

```
   matcher = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN).matcher(Birthday);

//Birthday validator
    else if (!matcher.matches()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Birthday!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORt).show();                    
}
```

Comment: спасибо! это то что я искал. нужно только разобраться 
вот в этом private static final String DATE_PATTERN = 
       "(0?[1-9]|1[012]) [/.-] (0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) [/.-] ((19|20)\\d\\d)"; Такое я уже встречал в некоторых примера по валидации даты. В остальном логика понятна. Проще говоря глянуть поподробней классы Pattern и Matcher

Comment: W4ereT1ckRtB1tch, если ответ Вам подошел - отметьте его как принятый.